# How to display data in-line while parsing it in ObjC, iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I've got a CSV text file of numbers that I would like to parse into an array and display on a graph. Allowing the parsing procedure to complete before displaying everything would result in a short period of nothing apparently happening.

So I'd like to display the data as it is parsed. Unfortunately I have very little experience in threading, so I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my own experience, your going to want to use GCD (Grand Central Dispatch). It is a low level C library that I use when some function needs to 'do something' then update the UI with the results.

Mainly you want to run the parser function in the background and then once the function is done, update the UI on the main thread.

Here is a link to what I did... [GCD example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980399/update-uitextview-during-recursive-function-is-running)

Here is another in depth example of GCD [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1)